# Possible to fool HTTPContext.Current?

Tags: c#

I have this line of code in an assembly:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath
```

This works great if the assembly is being used in a web service.

but if I take it out of the web service its obivously not going to work, because HTTPContext does not exist.

Is it at all possible to fool httpContext into thinking it exists, really just to get the relative path structure of a directory?

I mean somehow manually creating the HTTPContext object, and assigning it a base directory?

**Update**

Is there a more generic approach to : HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Something that can work in executables, and something that can work in web?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) "gets or **sets** the HttpContext object". And HttpContext has a public constructor which takes a HttpWorkerRequest (abstract, use SimpleWorkerRequest) and you would be able to fake the HttpContext completely.

I agree with others that you could refactor your code to remove this dependency, but there are scenarios when you must fake the HttpContext.Current stuff, in which case this question will show up if you search...

Answer (score 5):

It sounds to me like you need to wrap up the call to HttpContext inside another object which you can then switch out using IOC for the correct object in the correct environment. E.g. something like IMapPath as your interface and then your implementation could be HttpMapPath or ConsoleAppMapPath etc.

Answer (score 1):

We do something similar when writing unit tests that use HttpContext.Current.  We have an interface called IHttpContext which contains everything we need from the normal HttpContext.  Then, instead of calling HttpContext.Current, we have an extension method (HttpContext.Current.Make()) which returns this IHttpContext interface.

In the extension method we are then able to decide whether HttpContext.Current is usable, if it's not, then we're able to manually build up a "Testable" object and return that.

Of course, this extends to having to write IRequest, IResponse etc objects if you are using them, but I think that is to be expected

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help but I had a similar issue when writing some unit tests for an asp.net web app.  At some point in one of the api calls a property was being set by HttpContext.Current.XXXXX which was not in scope.  I found the answer was to add the following attributes to my unit test:

[TestMethod()]
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[UrlToTest("http://mytestsite.com/Home.aspx")]

[original article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182526(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Such code is web site specific. I wounder why does it belong in business logic.

Probably re-factor this code will to exclude `HttpContext` from business logic will be the best solution. For instance, you can accept the path to file as method parameter  instead of resolving it in business logic.